# Possibility to add new products to the Sagitta generic enabler in FIWARE

Tags: fiware, fiware-sagitta

I would like to use the Sagitta in order to deploy software in a VM in FIWARE, but I would like to know if there is a possibility in which users add new products to the Sagitta catalogue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Saggita does not give privileges to users to add products to the Catalog. However users can propose to add new products but the new products should be evaluated and, if valid, added to the catalog by the administrators.

Also a user as a GE owner could send to the administrators a product to be added to the catalog but the specifc actions of uploading the new product to the Catalog should be accomplished by administrators.